# MOSFET as inrush current limiter (passthrough parasitic C?)

Tags: mosfet, current-limiting, inrush-current

I have a circuit based on a P-FET which shall limit inrush current (20 mA).
However, when turning on the power supply there is always a current peak (30 mA, 5 ms) through the M1. Even if I tie its gate to the source.

My question is: What effect is causing that current peak?

- Is the P-FET initially conducting?
- Is there a capacitance in series with the P-FET which could be large enough to let that current pass?

Appreciate any hints.
If there are details missing in my description, my apology in advance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ0pcI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

@WhatRoughBeast I have updated the FET type.

---

In order to detail my last comment about counteracting the condition which leads to initial FET conduction (capacitive voltage divider) I'd like to draw what I have in mind. Maybe that helps to understand and discuss about.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAODJa.png)</sup>

So theoretically one would need a charge pump in order to cancel the inrush current through Cgs so no significant (less than Vgs_th) Vgs would develop.
The charge pump would need to be very fast.

What do you/others think?

Comment: IRF9530 is the default part number for a p-type MOSFET. What are you actually using? Edit your post, edit your schematic, then double-click on the FET and enter the number in the appropriate field.

Comment: Yes there will be an instant when the current is very large due to drain-source leakage mitigated by rise time of the power supply voltage. Voting to close as Op isn't answering comments and it gets very boring when this happens.

Comment: @Andyaka - We do not all live in the same time zone as "Stowoda", or you. If I can believe the numbers shown, you made the "isn't answering comments" comment 6 hours after the question was asked.  || I suggest you may need to better consider the " stowoda is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct." suggestion. Maybe I do too ? :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon he was now last seen 18 hours ago.

Comment: @Andyaka 19 now, here in NZ. In another 3 or 4 or so it will be 1 day since he posted, so the same time of day as when he posted. If he has less of a life than some (and more than many here :-) ) he may check daily. I'd be immensely surprised if the SE higher powers thought that 1 day delay, or even several, was a marvellously good reason to vote to close - especially for a new new user with 'Be nice' request officially attached to the post. If you want to feel fulfilled go and downvote something of Olin's. Or mine :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon but you and Olin aren't boring (AFAICT) and this guy still hasn't returned.

Comment: Hey :) I didn't know I need to react superfast. However there is still a weekend.@WhatRoughBeast I will update the type as soon as I know. Is shall some kidn of small signal FET. Just wanted to know what is happening. Meantime I have found some explanation: e.g. https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Parasitic_Turn-on_of_Power_MOSFET.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ed1d7b2011eee756cee5475

Comment: @Andyaka - Reset / NMI / ....

Comment: +1 @RussellMcMahon

Comment: The current reported by the OP does not seem right. 30mA for 5ms? I think the circuit is not connected properly. OP must have the drain and source mixed up, or used NMOS instead of PMOS. The parasitic capacitance cannot account for this. And in any event, adding a cap from gate to source is all that would be needed to fix it if it was parasitic capacitance.

Comment: @stowoda, when you say the gate was tied to the source, do you mean directly with a jumper or 0 Ohm resistor? If so, Cgs would be shorted out, so voltage across Cgs must be zero. In general, if you make Cgs much larger than Cgd (by adding a capacitor from gate to source) then all voltage will be across Cgd instead of Cgs. I think you probably have some other problem in your circuit. Maybe you could post a photograph of it so we can double-check wiring?

Comment: @stowoda - Welcome :-) Just to let you know that: (a) As you have now seen, answers are not the place to add updates to your question, so that has been moved to below the original question text. (b) The order of answers can be changed by readers. Therefore don't assume that just because any answer appears immediately below someone else's answer *for you*, that the same will be true for other readers. Therefore don't try to reply to "the answer above", and don't mention your "last comment" since that is ambiguous, depending on the display order, and so you may confuse people. Thanks.

Comment: @mkeith, the current is in that range. I agree that 30 mA could not flow through just the FET's parasitic capacitances. But I suggest, that a smaller current flows through these capacitances. This current is sufficient to charge up the gate. So in consequence the majority of that 30 mA current flows through the FET as it gets turned on. Your suggestion to add a parallel cap to Gate-Source parasitic capacitance makes sense but in practice it did not contribute much to limiting the inrush current. Maybe if it were just pure Capacitance without its inherent parasitics??

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting. I don't think the suggested explanation is on the right track. If it IS correct, then a large cap from gate to source would fix it for sure. Likewise, shorting gate to source with a piece of wire would also prevent the inrush. You say that you tried directly tying gate to source. Did you do that with a jumper wire? Or a resistor? Try doing it with a wire and see if you still have inrush.

Comment: @mkeith, Ok, large cap between Gate and Source prevents voltage rise across these terminals. I agree when AC-shorting Gate and Source with a large capacitor, the FET should not conduct. Also if I short it in a DC-manner with a wire no voltage difference should develop across Gate and Source. Given that the only answer would be that I am conducting the measurement in a wrong manner. I'll try to check that next.

Answer (score 2):

**Since you dont have any specs, no solution is [perfect.] = will meet spec.
Perhaps consider a Current sense cct amp. to drive the gate is what you need.
These are just ideas, not proven ccts.**
 - i.e. extremely dependent on load, Vt and RdsOn.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fywKKj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I changed it to a 240mA load.

But in your case, the ESR of your C1 is greater than the ESR of the Miller Capacitance of your FET

or try this instead to allow slow Vgs turn on.

Rev A

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwbdL3.png)</sup>

Comment: by any chance missing a cct with a capacitor between gate and drain ?

Comment: Almost.. Gate and Source with series R to Vgs(th)min

Comment: :) not positive feedback then. main point was no cct :)

Comment: syntax on initial schematic copy

Comment: If tested on breadboard, who knows what your stray reactance is.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist will have a closer look and try that. Thanks so far.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist: I am surprised by your circuit suggestion because I actually am thinking that the problem lies with the capacitive voltage divider formed by Cgs + Cgd + Cload. In other words this capacitive voltage divider yields a Vgs which rises above the Vgs_threshold and lets the FET conduct. If that is true, then I would need to add a capacitance in parallel to Cgs in order to "adjust" the capacitive voltage divider so the most voltage drops across Cgd (compared to Cgs drop). Please correct me if I am wrong. Regards.

Comment: You could be right. but my cct is sub-optimal anyways.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist: It is true I have not given a full specification. I think, here it is not needed though. I am just trying to get to know what you guys are thinking about the hypothesis concerning the capacitive voltage divider. So far I do not believe we are looking at the same goal. Stated that the capacitive voltage divider is the root cause of the initial current peak the question is how to avoid or counteract that behaviour.

Comment: R3 limits the transient Vgs which rises to the C-ratio C2/C1 roughly divides the 24 to drive 3xVt yet say below Vgs max.